# Android, AppBarLayout, app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" doesn't work

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

1. There are 2 children in AppBarLayout. If the first one use "scroll" as scrollFlags, it works; if the second one use "scroll", it doesn't work.
2. I have 3 views in my AppBarLayout. This is what I want:

   a. The first view uses "snap" or nothing to stay there. I don't want it to scroll away.

   b. The second view uses "scroll". When it scroll away, there were 2 views visible: the first one and the third one.

But it doesn't work. All the 3 views stay there just like "snap".
   Then I put the first view out of the AppBarLayout, but it covers the third view.

Here is the layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/appbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:elevation="1px">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="40dp">
       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="250dp"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">
       </RelativeLayout>

       <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/personal_tabs"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom"
           android:background="@drawable/titlebar_background"
           app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/personal_view_pager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you please paste some code here and comment which one you want to stay/hide

Comment: All of the 3 views dont scroll. Im trying to use two same views, hide one of them in AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener.

Comment: Docs for [`SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL) say `If any sibling views before this one do not have this flag, then this value has no effect.` Your second `RelativeLayout` won't scroll unless the one before it scrolls as well.